# Clicking on submit at billing address form redirects me at login, instead of redirecting me to shipping address form

Tags: python, django

I am following a tutorial explainig how to build an eCommerce app with django.

I have a **cart section [s1]** where the customer can see the resume of the products he/she has in the cart.
Here the customer can click on a "checkout" button that, according to the tutorial,

if the customer is logged in:

- should lead him/her to a **shipping address section [s2]** where he/she can fill the shipping address form.

else:

- should lead him/her to a **guest authentication section [s2-b]** where he/she can continue as guest (the customer is requested to submit his/her email address) or login (the customer is requested to submit user and password) and then reaches the shipping address form section [s2].

Then the app should lead the customer to a **billing address form [s3]** and then to a **finalizing section [s4]**.

My problem is that I can't go past the shipping address section [s3], because as I click on the submit button, the app redirects me to the login form, (this happens even if I am already logged in) where the message "This field is required" appears for both user and password files, and as I type those in and press Submit button, the app returns me back to the home page. So I can never reach billing address form [s4].

I don't understand what is wrong, here is my code:

`carts`, `billing` and `addresses` are my apps

**carts/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect       
from products.models import Product
from .models import Cart    
from orders.models import Order    
from accounts.forms import LoginForm    
from billing.models import BillingProfile    
from accounts.forms import GuestForm    
from accounts.models import GuestEmail    
from addresses.forms import AddressForm    
from addresses.models import Address


def cart_home(request):    
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)    
    return render(request, "carts/home.html", {"cart":cart_obj})


def cart_update(request):
    print(request.POST)
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id', 100) # il 2° arg è il default
    
    if product_id is not None:
        try:
            product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            print("product is gone?")
            return redirect("cart:home")    
        
    
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    
        if product_obj in cart_obj.products.all():
            cart_obj.products.remove(product_obj)
        else:
            cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
        
        request.session['cart_items'] = cart_obj.products.count()

    return redirect("cart:home")


def checkout_home(request):
    cart_obj, cart_created = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    order_obj = None

    if cart_created or cart_obj.products.count() == 0:
        return redirect("cart:home")    

    login_form = LoginForm()
    guest_form = GuestForm()
    address_form = AddressForm()
    billing_address_id = request.session.get("billing_address_id", None)
    shipping_address_id = request.session.get("shipping_address_id", None)

    billing_profile = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)


    if billing_profile is not None:
        order_obj, order_obj_created = Order.objects.new_or_get(billing_profile, cart_obj)
        
        if shipping_address_id:
            order_obj.shipping_address = Address.objects.get(id=shipping_address_id)
            del request.session["shipping_address_id"]

        if billing_address_id:
            order_obj.billing_address = Address.objects.get(id=billing_address_id)
            del request.session["billing_address_id"]

        if billing_address_id or shipping_address_id:
            order_obj.save()

    context = {

        "object": order_obj,
        "billing_profile": billing_profile,
        "login_form": login_form,
        "guest_form" : guest_form,
        "address_form" : address_form,
        

    }

    return render(request, "carts/checkout.html", context )
```

---

**addresses/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect    
from .forms import AddressForm
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url    
from billing.models import BillingProfile  

def checkout_address_create_view(request):

    form = AddressForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {"form":form}    

    next_ = request.GET.get('next')
    next_post = request.POST.get('next')
    redirect_path = next_ or next_post or None

    if form.is_valid():
        print("form is valid")
        print(request.POST)
        instance = form.save(commit=False)            

        billing_profile, billing_profile_created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)

        if billing_profile is not None:
            address_type = request.POST.get('address_type', 'shipping')
            instance.billing_profile = billing_profile
            instance.address_type = address_type
            instance.save()
            request.session[address_type +  "_address_id"] = instance.id
            print(address_type +  "_address_id")

        else:
            print("error here smth")
            return redirect("cart:checkout")

        # redirect to success page
        if is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
            return redirect(redirect_path)
        else:
            return redirect("cart:checkout")

    print("form is not valid")

    return redirect("cart:checkout")
```

---

**addresses/models.py**

```
from django.db import models    
from billing.models import BillingProfile    


ADDRESS_TYPES = (

    ('billing', "billing"),
    ('shipping', "shipping"),

    )


class Address(models.Model):
    billing_profile = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=ADDRESS_TYPES)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="Italy")
    state = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.billing_profile)
```

---

**billing/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings    
# from python_ecommerce.utils import unique_order_id_generator
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save    
from accounts.models import GuestEmail    

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class BillingProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        user=request.user
        guest_email_id = request.session.get('guest_email_id')
        created = False
        obj = None

        if user.is_authenticated:
            obj, created = self.model.objects.get_or_create(
                user=user, 
                email=user.email
                )

        elif guest_email_id is not None:
            guest_email_obj = GuestEmail.objects.get(id=guest_email_id)
            obj, created = self.model.objects.get_or_create(
                email=guest_email_obj.email
                )

        else:
            print("nè guest nè user")

        return obj


class BillingProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #OneToOneField
    email = models.EmailField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # customer is in stripe or brwwin

    objects = BillingProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

def user_created_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.email:
        BillingProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance, email=instance.email)

post_save.connect(user_created_receiver, sender=User)
```

---

**python_ecommerce/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import home_page, about_page, contact_page
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from carts.views import cart_home
from accounts.views import login_page, register_page
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
from accounts.views import guest_register_view
from addresses.views  import checkout_address_create_view


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', home_page, name="home"),
    path('about/', about_page, name="about"),
    path('contact/', contact_page, name="contact"),
    path('login/', login_page, name="login"),
    path('register/', register_page, name="register"),
    path('bootstrap/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='bootstrap/example.html')),

    path('', include("products.urls", namespace='products')), #spostato nell altro 
    path('', include("search.urls", namespace='search')),
    path('cart/', include("carts.urls", namespace="cart")),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('register/guest/', guest_register_view, name="guest_register"),
    path('checkout/address/create/', checkout_address_create_view, name='checkout_address_create_view'), 
    
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

---

**carts/templates/carts/checkout.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

{{ object.order_id }} &nbsp&nbsp {{ object.cart }}   



{% if not billing_profile %}
    <div class="row text-center">

        <div class='col-12 col-md-6'>
            <p class="lead">Login</p>
            {% include 'accounts/snippets/form.html' with form=login_form next_url=request.build_absolute_uri %}
        </div>

        <br><br><br>

        <div class='col-12 col-md-6'>
            continue as guest
            {% url 'guest_register' as guest_register_url %}
            {% include 'accounts/snippets/form.html' with form=guest_form next_url=request.build_absolute_uri action_url=guest_register_url %}   
        </div>

    <!-- qui è obbligatorio usare la struttura alias perchè non puoi mettere url tag dentro action_url= -->

    </div>

{% else %}

    {% if not object.shipping_address %}

    <div class=row>
        <div class='col-md-6 mx-auto col-10'>
            <p class='lead'>Shipping Address</p>

            <hr/>

            {% url 'checkout_address_create' as checkout_address_create %}
            {% include 'addresses/form.html' with form=address_form next_url=request.build_absolute_uri action_url=checkout_address_create address_type='shipping' %}   

        </div>
    </div>
    
    {% elif not object.billing_address %}
    <div class=row>
        <div class='col-md-6 mx-auto col-10'>
            <p class='lead'>Billing Address</p>

            <hr/>

            {% url 'checkout_address_create' as checkout_address_create %}
            {% include 'addresses/form.html' with form=address_form next_url=request.build_absolute_uri action_url=checkout_address_create address_type='billing' %}   

        </div>
    </div>

    {% else %}

        <h1>Finalize checkout</h1>

        <p>Cart total: {{ object.cart.total }}</p>
        <p>Shipping total: {{ object.shipping_total }}</p>
        <p>Order total: {{ object.total }}</p>
        <button>Checkout</button>

    {% endif %}

{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: please check what you are getting in request.build_absolute_uri in HTML, and next_ = request.GET.get('next') value in addresses/views.py I think absolute URL can be as login URL that's why when you submit the form you redirect to login.

Comment: From request.build_absolute_uri in HTML I get http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/checkout/ and from next_ = request.GET.get('next') in addresses/views.py I don't know because my code actually never reaches that point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

There was a very simple error in **python_ecommerce/urls.p**y:

In `urlspattern` I named `checkout_address_create_view` the view `checkout_address_create_view`, while in the template I call it as `checkout_address_create`, so the template could not find the function and don't know why was bringing me back to login form.

I substituted

```
path('checkout/address/create/', checkout_address_create_view, name='checkout_address_create_view'),
```

with

```
path('checkout/address/create/', checkout_address_create_view, name='checkout_address_create_view'),
```

and this solved that error.